# The most optimized way to load a big table through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am looking for loading a 1000 row X  100 column table through javascript most effciently .[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAVLV/2/)  uses the DomDocumentFragment to achieve this. It works fast enough in chrome and FireFox but is slow in IE . Can some one spot the reason of being slow in IE ? Also is there a better  solution ?  The solution can be using jquery.

Comment: Why would you load and display all of this content at once in the browser? What about paging or lazy loading rows?

Comment: I have no clue what your particular use case is, but 100 cols and 1000 rows seems like a pretty absurd amount of data to present a user, perhaps you should ask yourself if there's a better way to do what you want to do...

Comment: @Tejs lady loading is definitely an option. What is the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: Ajax is pretty much your only option.

Comment: I updated your fiddle using jQuery's `.html`, for the sake of curiosity, and I think it's slightly faster. [Here is it](http://jsfiddle.net/zAVLV/2/), in case it's useful for you.

Comment: @scumah Are you sure you provided the right link ?

Comment: not at all @Subhra xD sorry. here's the right one: http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/zAVLV/4/

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML can be faster than DOM manipulation. And replaceHTML can be faster than innerHTML.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml

Update: as pointed out in the comments, this really depends on what browser and version you're looking at. YMMV.

Comment: What about memory requirement?

Comment: That page is quite old - it seems 4 years old. Nowadays the DOM manipulation seems usually faster than innerHTML across browsers: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-or-dom/9. As the table describes, in some IE versions `innerHTML` seems still faster, so it depends what version are you targeting. For those IE versions, you could use innerHTML instead (maybe on a document fragment as well).

Answer (score 0):

here is a fiddle that behaves much faster than your original one by directly generating innerHTML code for your table body instead of constructing DOM Nodes.

http://jsfiddle.net/zAVLV/6/

Comment: doesn't the memory requirement also go up with this approach ? We can have more than one of such tables at any point of time.